# Can I change the difficulty level of a save game in Alpha Centauri?

Tags: alpha-centauri

I have just finished a great game of Alpha Centauri on Thinker level. The randomly generated map was great to play, and I would like to replay it on Transcend level.

I have an early save game; is there any way to change the difficulty level?

I am not looking for a complete save game editor, although that would would be very welcome, just something to change a single byte in the save file (the trick is to know what byte ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the difficulty level at any point in the game by activating the Scenario Editor. The only problem is that this will make you have a "Cheated" message displayed on your Alpha Centauri Score. On the main menu, go to **Scenario -> Activate Scenario Editor**. This will enable the menu option **Scenario -> Set Difficulty Level**. After you are done, once again click on **Scenario -> Activate Scenario Editor** to deactivate the Scenario Editor and resume regular gameplay.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanx a 1,000,000 ! Now, all I need to do is to find a way to reset the flag which says that I cheated :-)

Comment: Aha, [Can I reset the “cheat flag” in Alpha Centauri?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364196/can-i-reset-the-cheat-flag-in-alpha-centauri) tells me how to do that :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to edit difficulty of a saved game. You can only change difficulty at the start of a new game entirely.

Comment: That is what I feared :-(