# Can I reset the "cheat flag" in Alpha Centauri?

Tags: alpha-centauri

A follow-up to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334745/can-i-change-the-difficulty-level-of-a-save-game-in-alpha-centauri).

If I activate the scenario editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, the game remembers that I cheated. Does anyone know of a tool to reset this flag, or its offset in the save game file, which I can change with a hex editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> has been used to cheat, this will be saved in your savegame file (.sav) at hex offset 3C. You can clear the cheated flag by opening the save file with a hex editor and changing the value at offset 3C to 00.

Comment: Fantastic!  Do you know of any more good locations, such as the level of difficulty?